# how to upgrade from 14.0 to 18.0?

Tags: usb-installation

I have an intel pcstick running ubuntu 14.0, and I want to upgrade to 18 ubuntu mate. I have the software but the bios does not show a way to boot to usb or cd.

Comment: Do you remember how Ubuntu 14.04 was installed? Try the same way, if possible. You can also browse the internet with the search string 'install ubuntu intel pcstick' without quotes. (I found some links, that look promising.)

Comment: it came with the pcstick pre-installed (ub.14.0)

Comment: Maybe this link will help you get started, [Install Ubuntu-Mate on Windows Intel Compute Stick?](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/install-ubuntu-mate-on-windows-intel-compute-stick/2483) -- Tap the hotkey F2 or F7 or F10 right after [reboot] ...